# Read GetString for 2 languages from RESX results in an error in creating the migration with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I know the association between language resources in RESX files and *Entity Framework Core* seems crazy but I have an issue with it. This is my scenario. I have a `Persistence` class where I take care of the repositories and the seed of the database. In this project, I have a *Dictionary1.resx* with a list of words in English and a few others for localization in other languages. To simplify, I have the *Dictionary1.resx* and *Dictionary1.es-ES.resx*.

[image]

Now, I want to save the list of words in the database in both languages as a seed when the first time the application starts, and the database has not been created yet.

So, I call the `ResourceManager` to assign a different culture

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(
    "Dictionary1", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
CultureInfo esCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
```

Then, I try to add the word using the relative `CultureInfo`. For example:

```
public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Word>().HasData(
        new Word
        {
            ID = 61,
            WordName = rm.GetString("Actress", esCulture)
        }
    )
}
```

Now, I want to create the migration for the database, and I use the `add-migration` for it. When I run this one, I get this error from Entity Framework Core.

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Could not find the resource "Dictionary1.resources" among the resources "LIU.Persistence.Resources.Dictionary1.resources" embedded in the assembly "LIU.Persistence", nor among the resources in any satellite assemblies for the specified culture. Perhaps the resources were embedded with an incorrect name.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

If I comment the creation of the `Word`, *Entity Framework Core* can create the migration code. In the following screenshot, you can see the error. The red rectangle is when I comment the creation of the `Word`.

[image]

How can I read the localization from a different culture?

Comment: It has nothing to do with EF Core. The `baseName` argument of the `ResourceManager` constructor seems to be incorrect, should be `new ResourceManager("LIU.Persistence.Resources.Dictionary1", ...)`